# When is a generating function a probability generating function?

Tags: probability, probability-generating-fn

Given a generating function, say $G_1(z) = \frac{1}{1-z}$ it can be verified it is not a probability generating function by inspection that the sum of the probabilities (if it were a pgf) is not 100% by $G_1(1^-)\ne1$, and in fact $G_1(z)$ represents $G_1(z) = 1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4 + ...$

However, given a slightly modified version it is not so clear right away if it proper or under what conditions

$G_X(z;a,b,c) = \frac{a}{b-cz}$

we can see

$ G_1(1^-) = \frac{a}{b-c}$

equals one when $b=a+c$; however that only proves the sum is 100% and not necessarily all the probabilities are positive. In this case, in order for

$p(k) = \operatorname{Pr}(X = k) = \frac{G^{(k)}(0)}{k!}.$

to be positive for all $k$ we require

- $(c<0) \land (a<0)$ , or
- $(c>0) \land (a>0)$

Notice if we define $b=1$ (WLOG) we have $c=1-a$ and is a valid distribution (geometric) if $0<a<1$; in which case $G(z;a)=\frac{a}{1-(1-a)z}$. This we showed by illustration and worked out example.

I'm wondering is there a more general procedure.

Given an arbitrary generating function with some vector set parameters, $\theta$, is there a test to determine the conditions on $\theta$ in which the generating function $G(z;\theta)$ is a proper probability generating function for some distribution $X(\theta)$.

Is the necessary and sufficient conditions

- $G(1^-)=1$
- $G^{(k)}(0)>0 \quad \forall k=\{0,1,...\}$

The first can be checked by inspection, as we have done above, but is there a general test for the second condition?

Comment: Your conditions are a bit off. The correct conditions are that $G$ is a pgf iff i) $G$ is infinitely differentiable on $[0, 1)$ with $G^{(n)} \geq 0$ on $[0, 1)$ and ii) $G(1-) \leq 1$ with $G(1) = 1$.